# Response.Redirect adds the new Query-string on the existing Query-string?

Tags: vb.net

I have a Response.Redirect As follows :

```
Response.Redirect("http://192.168.50.3/Quoteman/Production/MachineSweepLite.aspx?AreaID=" + AreaID + "&Mobile=" + Mobile)`
```

When this event triggers off my button click and proceeds my Query-String looks as the follows:

```
http://192.168.50.3/Quoteman/Production/MachineSweepLite.aspx?AreaID=1#/Quoteman/Production/MachineSweepLite.aspx?AreaID=1&Mobile=App`
```

I've been stuck on this problem for a good 5 hours trying different ways in which to redirect the page but none have worked ( Javascript, many VB functions aswell ).

Does anyone know any reason this could be?

Comment: The URL fragment is not sent to the server at all.

Comment: Where are you getting the value of AreaID from?

Comment: AreaID = Request.QueryString("AreaID")

Answer (score 0):

Τhe variables AreaID, Mobile should have the values​​:

```
AreaID = 1 
Mobile = App
```

Instead the values ​​are:

```
AreaID = 1#/Quoteman/Production/MachineSweepLite.aspx?AreaID=1 (wrong) 
Mobile = App (correct)
```

the corect Query-String should be :

```
http://192.168.50.3/Quoteman/Production/MachineSweepLite.aspx?AreaID=1&Mobile=App
```

Check the variable AreaID.

Comment: If my Response Redirect just includes the AreaID it works , it's when i place the other parameter in there I get this error.

Comment: The url:
`http://192.168.50.3/Quoteman/Production/MachineSweepLite.aspx?AreaID=1#/Quoteman/Production/MachineSweepLite.aspx?AreaID=1&Mobile=App`
equals with
`http://192.168.50.3/Quoteman/Production/MachineSweepLite.aspx?AreaID=1`
because after the special character # is not taken into account the remaining characters.
Some questions what is the error message?
What happens when you write the url directly to your browser?
My advice would be to see if the variables (AreaID, Mobile) get the correct values​​, and what you expect to read in the page MachineSweepLite.aspx.